# How to protect admin routes from normal user with Sanctum token Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-middleware, laravel-sanctum

> I have admin and normal users. And I am using Laravel Sanctum for authentication APIs. When I am login from normal user and if I am using that same token in Admin APIs as Bearer token then that route is accessible by that token. I want to prevent admin route from normal user when they are trying to access using their token.

Comment: what makes something an "admin", what makes them a "normal" user?

Comment: @lagbox there are admin routes group and normal user routes group. And both routes group have sanctum middleware. Now, based on token can I protect admin routes to access by normal user?

Comment: what in your system designates a user as an admin or a regular user?

Comment: User have role. Admin user have admin role and normal user have user role. @lagbox

Comment: so you have a middleware to check roles? can't you assign that middleware?   if not you can write one pretty easily that takes a parameter for what role/roles you want to check for